# usage of sqlalchemy in aws lambda is failing on this error: errorMessage: the greenlet library is required to use this function

Tags: python, mysql, aws-lambda, sqlalchemy

Upon importing these module (below), I'm getting this error:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

```
{
  "errorMessage": "the greenlet library is required to use this function.",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 155, in lambda_handler\n    engine = create_db_engine(jiraSecret)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 50, in create_db_engine\n    db=secret['dbname']))\n",
    "  File \"<string>\", line 2, in create_engine\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py\", line 298, in warned\n    return fn(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py\", line 534, in create_engine\n    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py\", line 643, in _get_entrypoint\n    cls = registry.load(name)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py\", line 333, in load\n    loader = self.auto_fn(name)\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/dialects/__init__.py\", line 58, in _auto_fn\n    module = __import__(\"sqlalchemy.dialects.%s\" % (dialect,)).dialects\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/__init__.py\", line 57, in <module>\n    from . import asyncmy  # noqa\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/asyncmy.py\", line 175, in <module>\n    class AsyncAdapt_asyncmy_connection(AdaptedConnection):\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/asyncmy.py\", line 184, in AsyncAdapt_asyncmy_connection\n    @asynccontextmanager\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/util/concurrency.py\", line 63, in asynccontextmanager\n    _not_implemented()\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/sqlalchemy/util/concurrency.py\", line 38, in _not_implemented\n    \"the greenlet library is required to use this function.\"\n"
  ]
}
```

Is there a way around this error?  I have tried to manually install the greenlet library but it still fails on the same error.
Is this a version error?